# Avocado Tree Has Damage on Trunk

Tags: avocado

Question is what should I do here? Should I try and patch this? Looks like it began as sun damage.

[image]

Comment: It looks as if that branch is infected in some way - can you provide images of the rest of the plant please? and patching, as such, isn't something that can be done, specially as it looks like there's some kind of infection or infestation going on

Comment: I also can't tell whether the white fluff in the picture is one of the scale insects, or some kind of fungal growth, need a higher resolution image to be able to see that clearly please. You might check the rest of the plant to see if there is any evidence of scale or fungal growth elsewhere.

Comment: @Bamboo thanks that was a good clue: the rest of the tree was budding and going berserk. It's been a few months now and the white stuff is gone and the tree seems healthy, there is a ton of new growth on it. I bought that new worm bin the guy from New Zealand created, it's never been happier. Thanks.

Comment: Good news - hopefully it will continue to thrive